# Simple toggleClass on click not working on table

Tags: jquery, class

```
$('td').click({
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    $("td .selected").toggleClass("selected");
});
```

I get the error: **missing : after property id** on both those lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to say 'function()' :)

```
$('td').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    $("td .selected").toggleClass("selected");
});
```

Note that you were trying to pass an anonymous function to the click event. Without the `function()` keyword, the interpreter choked and threw those errors. Look at it like this:

```
//perfectly valid, but doesn't do anything
$('td').click(function(){});
```

Your toggleClass statements are just arbitrary expressions within the function:

```
//flesh it out with some behaviour
$('td').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    $("td .selected").toggleClass("selected");
});
```

It's called an anonymous function because it doesn't have a name. You can pass a named function like so:

```
function sayHello()
{
    alert('Hello!');
}

$('td').click(sayHello);
```

Comment: Bugger! I can't believe I missed that! Thanks!